# Print special characters in console

Tags: character-encoding, console, nim-lang

In my console (XP), the following line `echo "áéíóú"` in a utf-8 encoded file prints this:

`├í├®├¡├│├║`

Im not sure if this is something i have to handle in nim.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it works on Windows XP, but if you have Windows 8.1 your Nim code should be fine provided that in your console you change code page to  UTF-8 with the following command:

`chcp 65001`

You need **Lucida Console** font too.

Keep in mind that in the Output window of **Aporia** editor you don't need to change anything in order to see the correct characters.